# iPhone hardware audio decoding with multiple simultaneous audio files

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, avaudioplayer, hardware-acceleration

I'm developing an iPhone app that plays long (~30min) m4a audio clips. The clips are all stored locally and I'm using AVAudioPlayer to handle the playback functions. My app crossfades audio so that one sound fades out while another one fades in.

According to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009767-CH2-SW9) only one sound at a time will be played using hardware audio decoding. Assuming that the first sound is being hardware decoded and the second sound starts playing using software decoding, will the second sound switch to using hardware decoding once the first sound has finished playing, or will it use software decoding the entire time?

It seems like there's a [way to test](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/AudioFormatServicesReference/Reference/reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Hardware_Codec_Capabilities) for the availability of the hardware decoder. I'm going to see if that can get me the answer I'm looking for, but I was just curious if someone already knew the answer. Even if you just know the correct methodology for testing this, I'd appreciate it. This is my first iOS app and my first time working with C, so I'm flying blind.